# Java - Converting a continuing InputStream into a String without waiting for close

Tags: java, http, streaming, gzip, inputstream

So at the problem is that I have a gzipped connection to a remote http streaming server, which spews data out at a high rate, and I wish to process each line of data.

The connection is setup via the Apache ContentEncodingHttpClient, which connects correctly and I extract the InputStream via:

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

This works correctly. Now I wish to process it, my function seems to wait for the stream to end, which it never does.

```
final String result = convertStreamToString(is, "UTF-8");
                    new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                                r.gotResponse(result);
                        }
                    }.start();
```

The convert to string function is:

```
    public String convertStreamToString( InputStream is, String ecoding ) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( Math.max( 16, is.available() ) );
        char[] tmp = new char[ 4096 ];

        try {
           InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( is, ecoding );
           for( int cnt; ( cnt = reader.read( tmp ) ) > 0; )
                sb.append( tmp, 0, cnt );
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction for processsing content as it comes?

**EDIT**

I just got it to work with, which processes each line instead of appending each.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
return in.readLine();
enter code here
```

Comment: You could pass `is` to the getResponse method which reads and processes the data.

Comment: What's wrong with `EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity entity)` (for your sake, `String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`?

Comment: I tried `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` but the same problem occurs, it hangs waiting for the stream to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process each line of data, then can you not wrap the InputStream in an [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and wrap that in a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)?

The BufferedReader provides a [`readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method that can be used to read lines from the stream.

Comment: Thank You, but this fails too, it hangs and seems to wait for the stream to end. I used   `public String convertStreamToString( InputStream is, String ecoding ) throws IOException
  {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   String line = null;
   StringBuffer theText = new StringBuffer();
   while((line = in.readLine())!=null){
      theText.append(line+"\n");
   }

   return theText.toString();
  }`

Comment: Yes sorry, I think I didn't explain myself very well. You cannot wait for the stream to end, you must do your processing line-by-line as you read a line. This is what I thought you were asking for. So `line = in.readLine()` immediately followed by a call to `processLine(line)`, where this is your custom processing of that line.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that, it is perfect. Thank you very much :)